# Images slideshow doesn't align well with the rest of the page

Tags: html, css, alignment, slideshow

As suggest by a mate on another question I asked before, I stopped using ready made slideshows and am running my own.

I am running into two issues now, the slide show is not taking any space, i.e. the div with 'Some Other Stuff' below which is the div after the slideshow div is showing behind the slideshow photos instead of below it, which means the user will not be able to see it.

The other issue is that I can see the photos rendering behind each other while the page is loading before the slideshow start. Is there a way to hide all the photos, and show a in-progress image until all photos loads then start the slideshow?

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
    ...
</div>
<div>Some other stuff</div>
<script>
    function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('.slideshow img.active');

        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('.slideshow img:last');

        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
                    : $('.slideshow img:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
                    .addClass('active')
                    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
                    });
    }

    $(function() {
        setInterval('slideSwitch()', 5000 );
    });
</script>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.slideshow {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    width: 100%;
}

.slideshow img.active {
    z-index:10;
}

.slideshow img.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: `.slideshow` needs a height, it will not be sized according to the image size because image is `position: absolute;`, and `height: 100%;` wouldn't work until the parent container has a defined height.

Comment: but the whole idea was to make the slide show div fill the page when the page is resized.

Comment: Then set `.slideshow` height to `$(document).outerHeight(true)`, do the same inside `$(window).resize(function() {} );` too.

Comment: Sorry I am no expert, can you please explain what to do more slowly?